# Duda con nextDouble() de la clase Scanner en Java

Tags: java, consola, scanner

Hola estoy escribiendo un método que reciba parámetros con decimales , osea **double**, el problema es cuando escribo los decimales después del **.** (punto), me tira  error, cosa que no pasa cuando escribo en consola un numero entero. quisiera saber como poder escribir números con decimales en la consola.

````
public static void tomarValores() {
        int opcionDeseada;
        Scanner teclado;
        teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        double peso;
        double altura;
        byte edad;
        double datosRecibidos;
        byte edadRecibida;

        System.out.println("Ingrese Peso");
        datosRecibidos = teclado.nextDouble();
        peso = datosRecibidos;

        System.out.println("Ingrese Altura");
        datosRecibidos = teclado.nextDouble();
        altura = datosRecibidos;

        System.out.println("Ingrese Edad");
        edadRecibida = teclado.nextByte();
        edad = edadRecibida;

        ```
````

Comment: Agrega siempre el error en tus preguntas Rodrigo, saludos!

Comment: Agregar tabién una captuta de la consola para ver el problema.

Comment: [Revisa esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38695015/5587982), algunas configuraciones locales no aceptan el `.` como separador decimal. Puedes poner un local que use el punto o bien intentar poner los doble con coma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con las variables definidas como tipo `double` no tendrás problemas para almacenar valores con punto decimal pero debes tomar en cuenta que **las variables declaradas como tipo  `byte` no aceptan decimales y tiene un rango de -128 a 127**:

```
   byte edad;
   byte edadRecibida;
```

por lo tanto si tratas de definir decimales a esta variable obtendrás un error del tipo `java.util.InputMismatchException`, puedes definir estas variables también como tipo `double`.

Comment: En teoría no tendría por que guardar una edad como tipo double, aunque buena observación,

Comment: Exacto @Diego se supone que no es común almacenar edad con decimal.

Comment: Hola ya lo resolví , se ve que tengo la configuración en español, por que me tomaba las comas y no los puntos para los decimales. gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Hola ya encontré la respuesta a medias, por lo visto no me aceptaba los **puntos** para empezar a escribir los decimales, si no que me tomaba las **comas**, debe ser por que tengo una configuración en **español**, debería averiguar como configurar el idioma que toma en la consola.